# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) Prestashop

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://cofetariasweetmoments.ro/3-prajituri

Whenever I go on category page and try to go on next page, it's not working and show loading. in console i have a error and it's say that may be 3 causes:

1. Folders and Files permission
2. Server timeout
3. Incorrect syntax in `htaccess`

and i verify all permissions and they are all ok

I regenerate `htaccess`, and clear cache
I just moved the site on live, and when i had it on `localhost` i didn't have any problem.

Comment: have you checked the error_log?

Comment: It's nothing about this

Comment: Check again if the folder permission modules/blocklayered is 755, and the php files in that folder have the 644.

Comment: I had some files with permission 666, instead of 644, i changed them and know it's working. thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Without providen us log_errer, you was saying there are three possibilities. You eliminated two of them. So you have your response to your answer : Server Timeout. If the problem persists, it is because your answer is not corresponding to the problem. When a contributor ask the log, you should provide it. We are not supposed to guess but we're only developpers or system administrators. :-)